# Logback - delete the log file on startup

Tags: java, logback

I want to delete the log file each time the program is started as opposed to it being appended. I've tried using the cleanHistoryOnStart property but that seems to have no effect whatsoever. I'm probably missing something here.

I am on Linux and using Eclipse if that matters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="10 seconds">
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss} %level [%thread] %logger{20} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>chat.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <fileNamePattern>chat.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>
      <cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss} %level [%thread] %logger{20} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
    <Encoding>utf-8</Encoding>
  </appender>
  <logger name="src" additivity="false" level="ALL">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
  </logger>
  <root level="OFF">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 12):

Include `<param name="Append" value="false" />` in your appender to clean the log file on start up.

Otherwise try this one

http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-create-a-new-log-file-for-each-time-the-application-runs/

Comment: Setting the parameter `append` works perfectly with regular file appenders! Is it somehow possible to do the same when using a file appender in a `SiftingAppender`? I always get `No such property [append] in ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender` no matter if I place the `param` tag in the parent or child appender...

Comment: may be that appender have some other property.

Comment: Note to myself: I was able to solve this by using `<append>false</append>` within the `FileAppender` that is nested within the `SiftingAppender` (instead of  `<param name="Append" value="false" />`)

Comment: Hi @bluenote10

I added the properly <append>false</append> as you mentioned. But the issue is still not resolved. My logs are still appended to existing file.

`<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>filename.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">...</rollingPolicy></appender>`